# Run function immediately then run after specified time

Tags: javascript

```
function imgMan(){
var frames = 6;
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img-man')[0];
var frame = 1;
var animation = setInterval(function() { 
if (frame == frames) {
 clearInterval(animation); return; 
 }
    img.style.background = 'url(images/img-man-'+ frame++ + '.png) no-repeat';
    }, 140);
}
```

This will run the function after 140ms that is each image would be changed after 140ms. But I need to run the function immediately and after then changing image should be after 140ms.

How can I do that?

---

I'm having currently this:

after 140ms img-man-1 after 140ms img-man-2 after 140ms img-man-3 and like so

But I need this:

after 0ms img-man-1 after 140ms img-man-2 after 140ms img-man-3 and like so

Comment: You could name the function, then call it once before the setInterval and call the second time within the setInterval.

Comment: @C-link what the other are suggesting is what people call "factoring out code" - you basically need to break out the usable piece, name it, and call it everywhere that's needed.  Getting your code to be "one function to a function" (don't do too much in a function) will make this easier too.

Answer (score 3):

Just store it in a variable, and evoke it manually

```
function imgMan(){
  var frames = 6;
  var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img-man')[0];
  var frame = 1;
  var func = function() { 
    if (frame == frames) { clearInterval(animation); return; }
    img.style.background = 'url(images/img-man-'+ frame++ + '.png) no-repeat';
  };
  var animation = setInterval(func, 140);
  setTimeout(func, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yup this oughta do it!

Comment: it is not running the function now as I need to run the function outside the imgMan()...

Comment: @C-link I've edited the answer. It will run as soon as the stack clears.

Comment: @C-link: Then define it outside of `imgMan`.

Comment: @C-link What do you mean by "outside"? It will be evoked after `imgMan` finishes

Comment: from var animation or from setTimeout(func ... I should place outside?

Comment: @FelixKling He can't. The function encloses variables from the parent function.

Comment: Create a fiddel @C-link ,will be easier to help u out.

Comment: @C-link What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The changes I've made are trivial. Are you sure it worked before?

Comment: yes it was working before but after placing your code it's not working